# Castle windsor 3.0 and ASP.NET MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor 3.0 and it worked perfectly for me until I tried to register controllers (I used WCF facility and IoC for repository/service layer). Here is my controllers installer class:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        RegisterAllBasedOnWithCustomComponentRegistration(container, typeof(IController),
            typeof(HomeController).Assembly,
            cr => cr.LifeStyle.Transient);

    }

    private void RegisterAllBasedOnWithCustomComponentRegistration(IWindsorContainer container, Type baseType,
    Assembly assemblyWithImplementations, Func<ComponentRegistration, ComponentRegistration<object>> customComponentRegistrationCb)
    {
        container.Register(
            AllTypes.FromAssembly(assemblyWithImplementations)
                .BasedOn(baseType)
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .Configure(c => customComponentRegistrationCb(c)));
    }
}
```

And here is my controller factory:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerComponentName = controllerName + "Controller";
        return _kernel.Resolve<IController>(controllerComponentName);
    }
}
```

From my global.asax I call the next method:

> InversionOfControl.InstallControllers(FromAssembly.This());

which lies in an another project. And in there I do call the installation code:

```
    public static void InstallControllers(IWindsorInstaller install)
    {
        _container.Install(install);
    }
```

it seems like I am doing something wrong and I hope I am because it could be a "never use awny beta again" moment for me.

I get the next exception : **No component for supporting the service System.Web.Mvc.IController was found** altough I can see the controller in the debug mode being registered in the container

Comment: It's all there, in the exception message. It appears you're trying to resolve your controller as `IController` rather than its implementing class

Comment: Well, I am asking it to resolve exactly HomeController in controllerName, not the IController. May be I am asking it wrong, am not I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case add .WithServices(typeof(IController)) and name all components.

```
cr => cr.LifeStyle.Transient.Named(cr.Implementation.Name)
```

and your registration should look like:

```
.Register(
AllTypes.FromAssembly(assemblyWithImplementations)
        .BasedOn(baseType)
        .WithServices(typeof(IController))
        .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))...)
```

Comment: except the `WithService` part is wrong and will work only by accident, because you point to the specific component you want via its name, ignoring services it exposes.

Comment: yes you are right. In this case WindsorControllerFactory should be refactored as Mark Seemann suggested below.

Answer (score 9):

In your ControllerFactory, you don't shouldn't Resolve `IController` but rather the concrete controller type. Here's a typical Windsor-base ControllerFactory I always use:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry instead of up voting I accidentally down vote, I confirm that your solution is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. These things happen - no hard feelings :)